# Is the interior of a closed complex path is simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $ \delta: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C} $ be a closed simple path (i.e. $ \delta(0) = \delta(1) $ and $ \delta_{[0,1)} $ is injective), and let $ D $ be an open set such that $ \partial(D) = \delta([0,1]) $. Can we say that $ D $ is simply connected?

Warning: I changed the formulation to be more accurate, but I'm pretty sure the answer is still valid. So, according to Henno Brandsma, this true only if we take $ D $ to be bounded.

Comment: He probably means $\delta[(0,1)]$ ,I think.

Comment: I denote the image of $ \delta $ by $ \delta([0,1]) $.

Comment: The interior of a simple closed curve is empty (in $\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: You mean the bounded component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \delta[[0,1]]$, not the topological interior.

Comment: You write. I'll change to a more. Thanks

Comment: I meant "you right"...

Comment: In your new formulation there are 2 such $D$. Only the bounded one is simply connected

Comment: Interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interior region bounded by a simple closed curve in the plane is homeomorphic to the interior of the standard disk, and so it is simply connected.

This follows from a sharpening of the Jordan curve theorem known as [Jordan-Schoenflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem#Original_formulation).